# Custom Category Fields with in categories loop in LowReorder loop

Tags: add-on, categories, low-reorder

I'm not getting custom category fields to echo out within a `{categories}` loop that is also within a `{exp:low_reorder:entries}` loop. Any thoughts? Just outputs as the custom category field shortname string.

Comment: Can you post your full low_reorder:entries tag here, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I went to copy/paste over code, I realized I had the disabled="category_fields" parameter on the loop. Oddly enough, when that parameter is included, you can not access a custom category field.

Comment: This is exactly what should happen. If you have disabled="category_fields" set on your entries tag you are telling EE not to run the queries to get the category fields.